# How does pandas merge really sort its result when using its default, sort=False?

Tags: sorting, join, pandas, merge

I'm a bit confused how the default sort works when I run a merge/join with 2 pandas dataframes. I would expect the order of my result set from

```
A.merge(B, how='left', on=[Col1, Col2])
```

to be how A was previously sorted, but in my experience, the ordering is slightly off - and by the keys of A. I find that the order of A maintains, except when keys are duplicated, the result set is ordered by those keys. Below is a crude example of what I have been seeing.

```
A is:

    Col1      Col2      Col3
1    4          5         6
2    6          6         8
3    2          4         5
4    4          5         3

B is:

    Col1      Col2      Col4
1    6          6         0
2    2          4         5
3    4          5         7


A.merge(B, how='left', on=[Col1, Col2])

    Col1      Col2       Col3      Col4
1    4          5         6         7
2    4          5         3         7
3    6          6         8         0
4    2          4         5         5
```

Comment: It says that the default is `sort=True` in the pandas documentation. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging